# How can I export with texture properties

Tags: texturing, export

How can I export with texture properties
**For example:**

Object in blender:

[image: Object in blender]

I set texture sphere property:

[image: I set texture sphere property]

Object exported:

[image: Object exported]

Comment: That is going to depend on what you are exporting to.  There are several export formats that allow you to export textures, and each does it differently.  Can you tell us what application you're going to use with the exported data?

Comment: I exported it with .glb format. I open it with Microsoft 3D Viewer and I try to import it to Blender. I think the problem happen when I exporting it.

Comment: You need to bake the texture